# Fixed Point FFT Algorithm Needed

Tags: mobile, fft, fixed-point

I am developing an algorithm for an audio application for mobile platforms. It appears to me that currently the float point calculation support on many mobile processors is not ubiquitous and developing in fixed point would be a safer bet.

I have written FFT routines in float point form for some time now to a degree of success, however writing one in fixed point turned out to be rather difficult. Namely, I would be happy to improve the precision, as well as to find a way to handle potential overflows. The problem is, unlike float point FFTs, descriptions of fixed point FFT algorithms are hard to come by on the Internet.

Has anyone had some experience developing such algorithms?

Comment: If by mobile, you mean mobile phones, note that almost all smartphones currently shipping contain ARM processors that support hardware float arithmetic units. Maybe not for older mobile phones (PalmOS, Android 1.x, etc.) and button sensor type hardware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first choice should probably be to use a native-optimized FFT.  There are processing requirement for fixed point FFTs that are difficult to express efficiently in portable C (or any language probably): saturation arithmetic is probably the biggest obstacle.  Assembly libraries will tend to take advantage of processor-specific instructions for these .

If you still want a portable ANSI C fixed point FFT, I only know of one choice: [kissfft](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kissfft/). (Disclaimer : I wrote it)

Comment: Hi Mark, I actually have been reading through your code a couple days ago, it does seem that yours is the only ready to go solution on the Internet for fixed point FFT. You are possibly right about the need to be looking for the platform native FFT in order to get optimal performance, I'll look into that.

Answer (score 3):

I have read great things about http://anthonix.com/ffts/index.html - this works well on mobile platforms - The site contains benchmarks

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about this one, but I fear it is written for float point too.

Answer (score 2):

I have been working on an automated tool that converts floating-point C code to fixed-point, with a variety of options for tradeoffs between accuracy and execution time. I have had good results with a number of algorithms, including a 2D 8x8 discrete cosine transform. My target platform is typically an ARM Cortex-M processor but similar results should be achievable on other platforms. Would you be interested in letting me take a crack at your FFT?

Comment: Yeah, that would be great, only would the fact that I work in Common Lisp be a problem? I could rewrite it in C, if necessary, but that would take a day or two.